# how to pass values between methods from external class

Tags: c#

I've been looking for an answer but couldnt find one that matched my problem and/or couldnt understand those which don't match my example.
Here is an example of my problem:

In Form.cs,

```
namespace Test
public partial class Form
`{
    public void firstmethod()
     {
     enregistre enr = new enregistre();
     enr.date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
     }

    public void secondmethod()
    {
    enregistre enr = new enregistre();
    textBox1.Text = enr.date;
    }
```

In my program.cs
I have:

```
namespace Test
public class enregistre
{
 public DateTime date { get; set; }
 }
```

My problem is : inside the same method I can call enr.date as often as I want and it keeps the values set or returned, but when I call it from the next method, it returns " 01/01/0001 " ... How can I keep values between methods while stored on another class?
I understand I could have just use " public DateTime date" right under "public partial class
{"  but I wrote more than 1000 lines now using this other class.. any way to fix this without rewriting everything?
If one could write a solution using this example code that would be very useful.
Thank you.

Comment: Set up a private member in the Class - set it to the time,  then set that private member where you want to use it.
When you instancate a new Object, it has a New Reference, and since you did not set it, it call back to the default 01/01/0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare it static so that it retains its values between instances.

```
 namespace Test
 public static class enregistre
 {
     publist static DateTime date {get;set;}
 }
```

Now when you call it you use 
     enregistre.date = DateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();

When you use instance variables, (no static descriptor) the variables are reinitialized for every instance, meaning every time you call `new <classname>`.  When you want to keep values between invocations, use static.

Comment: This is exactly it ! Thanks a lot for your quick and accurate reply !

Answer (score 1):

Your first method and the second one use different instances of the same class. For being able to share information between them you should use the same instance.

```
public partial class Form
 {
    public enregistre Enr {get; private set;}

    public void firstmethod()
     {
      Enr = new enregistre();
      Enr.date = dateTimePicker1.Value.ToShortDateString();
     }

    public void secondmethod()
    {
      textBox1.Text = Enr .date;
    }
  }
```

Comment: unfortunatly I get a "NullReferenceException" on enr.date on the second method, and if I redeclare a new instance of enregistre the value is 01/01/0001

Comment: That is because Enr property is instantiated in firstmethod, only after calling first method you'll be able to access it from second one.

Answer (score 0):

When you call it from the second method, you're getting a different value back because you're calling `date` on a different `enregistre` object.  If you change the `date` property to be static, then there will be only one `date` which applies to the entire `enregistre` class, not to each instance of that class.  An alternative solution is to create the `enregistre` in the caller of the two methods in your `Test.Form`, then pass it into each of those methods as a parameter.

Comment: yes thank you you are right I had no idea how "static" worked.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not modify your enregistre class as follows to preserve the date value:

```
public class enregistre {
    private static Nullable<DateTime> _date;

    public DateTime date {
        get {
            return _date.HasValue() ? _date.Value : default(_date);
        }
        set {
            _date = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Since in your method, you are creating a new instance of enregistre(), between methods within a class, it will be difficult to preserve the property value unless you make some changes to code as you already indicated.